# select two fields from one table

Tags: sql

I want select two fields from one table.

```
SELECT Book.Id,
    Book.fristTitle,
    Book.secondTitle,
    Person.fName +' ' + Person.lName as author,
    (Person.fName +' ' + Person.lName) as translator,
    Subject.subjectTitle,
    isbn,
    editionNumber,
    state,
    type
FROM Book
INNER JOIN Subject ON Book.subjectId=Subject.Id 
INNER JOIN Person ON Book.authorId=Person.Id
    where Person.isAuthor=1
INNER JOIN Person ON Book.authorId=Person.Id
    where Person.isTranslator=1
```

Where the first field is `(Person.fName +' ' + Person.lName)` as the author and second field is `(Person.fName +' ' + Person.lName)` as translator in library Database

Comment: I couldn't work out what "filde" means. Is it "rows"?

Comment: I assume he means field > column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
string query = SELECT Book.Id, Book.fristTitle, Book.secondTitle,
                      A.fName +' ' + A.lName as author,
                      (T.fName +' ' + T.lName) as translator,
                      Subject.subjectTitle, isbn, editionNumber, state, type
               FROM Book
               INNER JOIN Subject ON Book.subjectId=Subject.Id 
               INNER JOIN Person as A ON Book.authorId = A.Id and A.isAuthor=1
               INNER JOIN Person as T ON Book.authorId = T.Id and T.isTranslator=1
```

You need to join into Person twice but alias it each time to distinguish which set of data is which.

You can't have two `WHERE` clauses (a mistake I originally repeated when I copied your code) so you use the `AND` to control the join.

Answer (score 0):

While I think you may still be missing something, you're query should look more like this:

```
SELECT Book.Id, Book.fristTitle,Book.secondTitle,
       P1.fName +' ' + P1.lName as author,
       P2.fName +' ' + P2.lName as translator,
       Subject.subjectTitle,isbn,editionNumber,state,type
FROM Book 
    INNER JOIN Subject ON Book.subjectId=Subject.Id 
    INNER JOIN Person P1 ON Book.authorId=P1.Id AND P1.isAuthor=1
    INNER JOIN Person P2 ON Book.authorId=P2.Id AND P2.isTranslator=1
```

Generally with this approach though, your `Book` table would have 2 fields -- one for `author` and one for `translator`...

---

BTW -- With this approach, you'd have to have multiple rows in the `Person` table with the same `Id` (1 for `IsAuthor = 1` and 1 for `isTranslator = 1`).  If this is the case, I'd highly recommend looking into database normalization.

A better approach is to have an `authorid` field and a `translatorid` field on the `book` table.